# How to convert a list of attribute-value pairs into a flat table whose columns are attributes

Tags: sql, database, perl, csv, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a csv file containing 3 columns (`ATTRIBUTE_NAME,ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,ID`) into a flat table whose each row is (`ID,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3,....`). The samples of such tables are provided at the end.

Either Python, Perl or SQL is fine. Thank you very much and I really appreciate your time and efforts!

In fact, my question is very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010489/convert-tables-with-id-attribute-value-columns-to-id-attribute1-attribute2), except that in my case the number of attributes is pretty big (~300) and not consistent across each ID, so hard coding each attribute might not be a practical solution.

For me, the challenging/difficult parts are:

- There are approximately 270 millions lines of input, the total size of the input table is about 60 GB.
- Some single values (string) contain comma (`,`) within, and the whole string will be enclosed with double-quote (`"`) to make the reader aware of that. For example `"JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA, TX"` in ID=53.
- The set of attributes is not the same across ID's. For example, the number of overall  attributes is 8, but ID=53, 17 and 23 has only 7, 6 and 5 respectively. ID=17 does not have attributes `string_country` and `string_address`, so output `blank/nothing` after the comma.

The input attribute-value table looks like this. In this sample input and output, we have 3 ID's, whose number of attributes can be different depending on we can obtain such attributes from the server or not.

```
ATTRIBUTE_NAME,ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,ID
num_integer,100,53
string_country,US (United States),53
string_address,FORT WORTH,53
num_double2,546.0,53
string_acc,My BankAcc,53
string_award,SILVER,53
string_bankname,"JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA, TX",53
num_integer,61,17
num_double,34.32,17
num_double2,200.541,17
string_acc,Your BankAcc,17
string_award,GOLD,17
string_bankname,CHASE BANK,17
num_integer,36,23
num_double,78.0,23
string_country,CA (Canada),23
string_address,VAN COUVER,23
string_acc,Her BankAcc,23
```

The output table should look like this. (The order of attributes in the columns is not fixed. It can be sorted alphabetically or by order-of-appearance.)

```
ID,num_integer,num_double,string_country,string_address,num_double2,string_acc,string_award,string_bankname
53,100,,US (United States),FORT WORTH,546.0,My BankAcc,SILVER,"JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA, TX"
17,61,34.32,,,200.541,Your BankAcc,GOLD,CHASE BANK
23,36,78.0,CA (Canada),VAN COUVER,,Her BankAcc,,
```

Comment: It looks like you're convert a CSV file to another CSV. Where does SQL figure into this?

Comment: Hi @runrig I'm OK with Python and R, but can understand Perl a bit. I'm trying Python right now.

Comment: Hi shawnhcorey, Yes, you are right. It's about converting csv file to another csv file indeed. I mentioned SQL because I just thought that SQL might provide some function that does that automatically, but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program will do as you ask. It expects the name of the input file as a parameter on the command line.

**Update** Looking more carefully at the data I see that not all of the data fields are available for every ID. That makes things more complex if the fields are to be kept in the same order as they appear in the file.

This program works by scanning the file and accumulating all the data for output into hash `%data`. At the same time it builds a hash `%headers`, that keeps the position each header appears in the data for each ID value.

Once the file has been scanned, the collected headers are sorted by finding the first ID for each pair that includes information for both headers. The sort order for that pair within the complete set must be the same as the order they appeared in the data for that ID, so it's just a matter of comparing the two position values using `<=>`.

Once a sorted set of headers has been created, the `%data` hash is dumped, accessing the complete list of values for each ID using a hash slice.

**Update 2** Now that I realise the sheer size of your data I can see that my second attempt was also flawed, as it tried to read *all* of the information into memory before outputting it. That isn't going to work unless you have a monster machine with about 1TB of memory!

You may get some mileage from this version. It scans twice through the file, the first time to read the data so that the full set of header names can be created and ordered, then again to read the data for each ID and output it.

Let me know if it's not working for you, as there's still things I can do to make it more memory-efficient.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Text::CSV;
use Fcntl 'SEEK_SET';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die qq{Unable to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!};

my %headers = ();
my $last_id;
my $header_num;
my $num_ids;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
  next if $. == 1;

  my ($key, $val, $id) = @$row;

  unless (defined $last_id and $id eq $last_id) {
    ++$num_ids;
    $header_num = 0;
    $last_id = $id;
    print STDERR "Processing ID $id\n";
  }

  $headers{$key}[$num_ids-1] = ++$header_num;
}

sub by_position {
  for my $id (0 .. $num_ids-1) {
    my ($posa, $posb) = map $headers{$_}[$id], our $a, our $b;
    return $posa <=> $posb if $posa and $posb;
  }
  0;
}

my @headers = sort by_position keys %headers;
%headers = ();
print STDERR "List of headers complete\n";

seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;
$. = 0;

$csv->combine('ID', @headers);
print $csv->string, "\n";

my %data = ();
$last_id = undef;

while () {
  my $row = $csv->getline($fh);
  next if $. == 1;

  if (not defined $row or defined $last_id and $last_id ne $row->[2]) {
    $csv->combine($last_id, @data{@headers});
    print $csv->string, "\n";
    %data = ();
  }

  last unless defined $row;
  my ($key, $val, $id) = @$row;
  $data{$key} = $val;
  $last_id = $id;
}
```

**output**

```
ID,num_integer,num_double,string_country,string_address,num_double2,string_acc,string_award,string_bankname
53,100,,"US (United States)","FORT WORTH",546.0,"My BankAcc",SILVER,"JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA, TX"
17,61,34.32,,,200.541,"Your BankAcc",GOLD,"CHASE BANK"
23,36,78.0,"CA (Canada)","VAN COUVER",,"Her BankAcc",,
```

Comment: Maybe the output should be flushed as soon as the ID changes... after all, it's 60GB of input.

Comment: Sheesh. I didn't see the 60GB. That means my new code won't work either :-/ Thanks Slaven.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! I will test it with the 60GB input and let you know. Though I will study more about how to flush the output.

Comment: @user1613297: My previous version isn't going to work for you as it will use up far too much memory. Also, flushing the output won't make any difference as it is flushed every 8KB anyway by Perl. Try with the code above. It may take a while to read the list of headers, and it might be useful to put some `print STDERR` trace in so that you know it's doing something.

Comment: @Borodin: I have tested the new version of your code already, and it works really well with medium-sized file. I'm testing it with bigger files now. Again, thanks for your contribution here; and I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: @Borodin: I made the code to output to a csv file and ran the code on 150 millions attribute-value pairs/lines (4.6 GB .csv file). It worked very well and took around 6 hours to finish on a 8GB-memory Core-i5 Ubuntu box. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1613297: You're welcome. I'm glad it worked for you and my fears weren't realised!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text::CSV` [from CPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------

use charnames qw( :full :short   );
use English   qw( -no_match_vars );  # Avoids regex performance penalty

use Text::CSV;

my $col_csv     = Text::CSV->new();
my $id_attr_csv = Text::CSV->new({ eol=>"\n", });

$col_csv->column_names( $col_csv->getline( *DATA ));
while( my $row = $col_csv->getline_hr( *DATA )){

  # do all the keys but skip if ID
  for my $attribute ( keys %$row ){
    next if $attribute eq 'ID';

    $id_attr_csv->print( *STDOUT, [ $attribute, $row->{$attribute}, $row->{ID}, ]);

  }
}

__DATA__
ID,num_integer,num_double,string_country,string_address,num_double2,string_acc,string_award,string_bankname
53,100,,US (United States),FORT WORTH,546.0,My BankAcc,SILVER,"JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA, TX"
17,61,34.32,,,200.541,Your BankAcc,GOLD,CHASE BANK
23,36,78.0,CA (Canada),VAN COUVER,,Her BankAcc,,
```

Comment: @shawnhcorey I'm checking this solution, and I will get back to you soon. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I got the output columns in the wrong order. It's corrected now.

Comment: I have tested your code already, and it looks like your code do the opposite way, that is, converting from the attributes table back to the attribute-value list file. In fact, this is useful too! Thanks again for your help.